# Array.prototype.every() - get the falsy value element

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function ,

how could I get the *falsy* element ?   for example -

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 10;
}
[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].every(isBigEnough);   // get the element "5" (falsy)
```

Comment: You would better use `Array.prototype.filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a filter:

```
function tooSmall(element){
    return element < 10
}

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(tooSmall) // gives [5, 8]

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(tooSmall)[0] // gives the first element ie 5
```

If you want to stick with the too big function then you could use:

```
function not(fn) {
    return function(){
        return !fn.apply({},arguments)
    }
}

[12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(not(isBigEnough)) // [5, 8]
```

Comment: I want to get  1st element that hold the filter check .

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers/comments that you want to use filter.  However I'm interpreting your question differently in another aspect.  How I interpret what you're asking is, once you have filtered down to `bigEnough` how can you then also filter down to *not* big enough.

One answer to this would be to use underscore's `_.difference` method:

```
var entireArray = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44];
var bigEnoughVals = entireArray.filter(isBigEnough); 
var tooSmallVals = _.difference(entireArray, bigEnoughVals);

function isBigEnough(element, index, array) {
  return element >= 10;
}
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#difference